# How to show that $\omega (e)$ is a $2$-cocycle on $\mathfrak g\ $?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, differential-forms

> Let $G$ be a Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak {g}.$ Let $\omega$ be a left-invariant non-degenerate closed $2$-form on $G.$ Then $\omega (e)$ is a $2$-cocycle on $\mathfrak {g}$ i.e. $$\omega (e) ([a,b], c) + \omega(e) ([b,c], a) + \omega (e) ([c,a], b) = 0$$ for all $a,b,c \in \mathfrak {g},$ where $[\cdot, \cdot]$ is the Lie bracket on $\mathfrak {g}.$

How to prove it? Any help in this regard would be warmly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What have you tried already? You have that $\omega$ is left-invariant and closed. You can extend $a$, $b$, and $c$ to left-invariant vector fields....

Comment: @MatthewLeingang How does the first summation $\sum_{i=1}^3 (-1)^{i}[X_i,\omega (X_1\wedge \hat X_i\wedge X_3)]$ vanish?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang$:$ You can extend mean what? How does it help? I can't see how does that give the desired equality. Sorry!

Comment: @MatthewLeingang$:$ Left invariance of $\omega$ means that for all $x,y \in G$ we have $$(\lambda_x)^{\ast} (\omega (y)) = \omega (x^{-1} y)$$ where $(\lambda_x)^{\ast}$ is the pullback of $\lambda_x.$

Answer (score 0):

First prove this lemma: If $\omega$ is a left-invariant differential $2$-form on $G$, and $X$ and $Y$ are left-invariant vector fields on $G$, with $X_e = \xi$ and $Y_e = \eta$ in $\mathfrak{g}$, then
$$ 
    \omega(X,Y)_g = \omega(X,Y)_e = \omega_e(\xi,\eta)
$$
To clarify the notation:

- $\omega$ is a differential $2$-form, while $X$ and $Y$ are vector fields, so $\omega(X,Y)$ is a function on $G$.
- $\omega(X,Y)_g$ denotes the value of that function at a point $g \in G$.
- $\omega_e$ is an element of $\left(\bigwedge^2 T_e G\right)^* = \left(\bigwedge^2 \mathfrak{g}\right)^*$.
- $\omega_e(\xi,\eta)$ is the value of $\omega_e$ on $\xi \wedge \eta$

In particular, notice that *$\omega(X,Y)$ is a constant function on $G$.*

The proof of this lemma requires carefully writing out the definitions of left-invariant, both for vector fields and for differential forms.

Now to prove the main statement: let $\xi$, $\eta$, and $\zeta\in\mathfrak{g}$. There are unique left-invariant vector fields $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ on $G$ such that $X_e = \xi$, etc. Observe that
$$
   d\omega(X,Y,Z) = X \omega(Y,Z) - Y \omega(X,Z) + Z \omega(X,Y) - \omega([X,Y],Z) + \omega([X,Z],Y) - \omega([Y,Z],X)
$$
Once again, to clarify the notation: $\omega(Y,Z)$ (etc.) is a function on $G$, and $X$ is a vector field on $G$. $X \omega(Y,Z)$ means the derivative of $\omega(Y,Z)$ in the direction of $Z$. This is a function on $G$.

Since $\omega$, $Y$, and $Z$ are left-invariant, $\omega(Y,Z)$ is constant. Therefore $X\omega(Y,Z) = 0$. The same for the next two terms in the expansion of $d\omega(X,Y,Z)$.

In light of the fact that $d\omega = 0$, we have
$$
    \omega([X,Y],Z) + \omega([Z,X],Y) + \omega([Y,Z],X) = 0
$$
as functions on $G$. Evaluating at $g=e$ gives
$$
    \omega_e([\xi,\eta],\zeta) + \omega_e([\zeta,\xi],\eta) + \omega_e([\eta,\zeta],\xi) = 0
$$
QED